# mongo add to nested array if entry does not contain two fields that match

Tags: arrays, mongodb, upsert, database

I have a mongo document that contains an array called history:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575fe85bfe98c1fba0a6e535"),
    "email" : "email@address",
    "__v" : 0,
    "history" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Test123",
            "organisation" : "Rat",
            "field" : 4,
            "another": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add fields to each history object or update fields **IF** the name AND organisation match, however if they don't, I want to add a new object to the array with the queried name and organisation and add/update the other fields to the object when necessary.

So:

This query, finds one that matches:

```
db.users.find({ 
    email:"email@address",
    $and: [
        { "history.name": "Test123", "history.organisation": "Rat"}
    ]
})
```

However, I'm struggling to get the update/upsert to work IF that combination of history.name and history.organisation dont exist in the array.

What I think I need to do is a :

"If this history name does not equal 'Test123' AND the history organisation does not equal 'Rat' then add an object to the array with those fields and any other field provided in the update query."

I tried this:

```
db.users.update({ 
    email:"email@address",
    $and: [
        { "history.name": "Test123", "history.organisation": "Rat"}
    ]
}, {
    history: { name: "Test123"},
    history: { organisation: "Rat"}
}, {upsert:true})
```

But that gave me `E11000 duplicate key error index: db.users.$email_1 dup key: { : null }`

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks community!

Comment: are you going to find matched document to ` email:"email@address"`
and set those two fields in array? Maybe update them always is an option?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with a single atomic update I'm afraid, you would have to do a couple of update operations that satisfy both conditions.

Break down the update logic into two distinct update operations, the first one would require using the [positional **`$`** operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to identify the element in the `history` array you want and the **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)** to update the existing fields. This operation follows the logic ***update fields IF the name AND organisation match***

Now, you'd want to use the **[`findAndModify()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify)** method for this operation since it can return the updated document. By default, the returned document does not include the modifications made on the update.

So, armed with this arsenal, you can then probe your second logic in the next operation i.e. ***update IF that combination of "history.name" and "history.organisation" don't exist in the array***. With this second 
update operation, you'd need to then use the **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push)** operator to add the elements.

The following example demonstrates the above concept. It initially assumes you have the query part and the document to be updated as separate objects.

Take for instance when we have documents that match the existing history array, it will just do a single update operation, but if the documents do not match, then the **[`findAndModify()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify)** method will return null, use this logic in your second update operation to push the document to the array:

```
var doc = {
        "name": "Test123",
        "organisation": "Rat"
    }, // document to update. Note: the doc here matches the existing array
    query = { "email": "email@address" }; // query document

query["history.name"] = doc.name; // create the update query
query["history.organisation"] = doc.organisation;
var update = db.users.findAndModify({
    "query": query,
    "update": { 
        "$set": { 
            "history.$.name": doc.name,
            "history.$.organisation": doc.organisation
        }
    }
}); // return the document modified, if there's no matched document update = null

if (!update) {
    db.users.update(
        { "email": query.email },
        { "$push": { "history": doc } }
    );
}
```

After this operation for documents that match, querying the collection will yield the same

```
db.users.find({ "email": "email@address" });
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575fe85bfe98c1fba0a6e535"),
    "email" : "email@address",
    "__v" : 0,
    "history" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Test123",
            "organisation" : "Rat",
            "field" : 4,
            "another" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Now consider documents that won't match:

```
var doc = {
        "name": "foo",
        "organisation": "bar"
    }, // document to update. Note: the doc here does not matches the current array
    query = { "email": "email@address" }; // query document

query["history.name"] = doc.name; // create the update query
query["history.organisation"] = doc.organisation;
var update = db.users.findAndModify({
    "query": query,
    "update": { 
        "$set": { 
            "history.$.name": doc.name,
            "history.$.organisation": doc.organisation
        }
    }
}); // return the document modified, if there's no matched document update = null

if (!update) {
    db.users.update(
        { "email": query.email },
        { "$push": { "history": doc } }
    );
}
```

Querying this collection for this document

```
db.users.find({ "email": "email@address" });
```

would yield

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575fe85bfe98c1fba0a6e535"),
    "email" : "email@address",
    "__v" : 0,
    "history" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Test123",
            "organisation" : "Rat",
            "field" : 4,
            "another" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "foo",
            "organisation" : "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is great, and what if I want to increment the fields `field` and `another` if those fields already exist, but add them (and set them to 1) if they don't exist?
I know whether the object is in the array from `name` and `organisation`, and if not, to create it, but can I increment/add other fields based on this?

Comment: The concept should be the same, not far-fetched; you can include the [**`$inc`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#up._S_inc) operator as well in both updates side-by-side with the `$set` and `$push` operators. For more info, see the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/)

Comment: I've added: `"$inc": { "history.$.score": 5 }` to the `findAndModify` and it does increment it, but it increments the wrong history entry. Possibly its incrementing the first history object it comes across. It looks like the `query` should handle this, but alas it doesn't seem so

Comment: OK Will create new question, I tried changing:
```
query = { "email": "email@example", history: {}}; // query document
    query.history.name = doc.name; // create the update query
    query.history.organisation = doc.organisation;
```
that just created a new object in the array each time

Comment: The positional `$` operator only identifies the first element in the array that matches the query part, the linked [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) describes its anatomy. Not too sure how to address the other question but if you could create another question that would be great.