# Editing a result from mongo, and writing it back to database (javascript/node)

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have to do quite a complicated query, that after asking a question here, reading around and realising life can sometimes be too short, I have found the easiest way to do what I want to do is to retrieve the document from Mongo, edit the response in my JavaScript application and write the response back. To illustrate:

```
{objectname: "name"
array: [
    {
        name: "jamesbond"
        organisation: "007"
    }
]}
```

My JavaScript code adds a `score` field to the object in the array, when `name = "jamesbond"` and `organisation = "007"`

That's all fine. However, sometimes it doesn't write the changes to the database, to clarify I am retrieving the document, editing the response and then calling

```
self.update({
    objectname: "name"
}, {
    $set: { "array": response.array }
})
```

For some reason that I cannot understand, this doesn't always write the update. I just cant tell why. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. I wondered whether its because I am editing the original response, should I be creating a new object that I write the database?

I learnt from the answer in the following link, that the `.$.` operator won't be much help because it returns the first element in the array, hence why I am loading the object, editing it and restoring it:

[mongo add to nested array if entry does not contain two fields that match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815233/mongo-add-to-nested-array-if-entry-does-not-contain-two-fields-that-match)

Comment: Do you have any sample code you can share

Comment: Yep, I'll add it as an edit at the bottom of original post. Slightly less abstract than my James Bond example.. Done... The above does sometimes update the score, but sometimes it doesn't. I cant tell why...

Comment: What if before finishing the `for` loop and `if` statement, `update` will be called? Have you tried doing update with `callbacks`?

Comment: why would the update be called before the `for` and `if`? I thought because those were synchronous they would happen in order? Otherwise I will have to use `async` or promises to make the `update` happen after those have finished...